# for every request in rails, is it normal to 'get' assets in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my sample rails app, i'm refreshing my page to see what happens.

with every refresh, i'm seeing other things like

```
Started GET "assets/welcome.self[...]" 
Started GET "assets/application.self[...]"
```

... + maybe 6 other "GET xxxxxx " things along.

files are css and js.

for every view folder i have, i think it's doing this. like "assets/profiles ~~etc"

this is not a good thing, is it? all my js and css files for those are empty. I only have some code within the application.css and application.js.

Comment: In dev mode assets are fetched individually. In production the asset pipeline glomps them all together. If you have empty, unused files, you should delete them--they're empty.

Comment: @DaveNewton i'll delete them.  I don't get why i'd need JS/CSS files for each of my controller generated? i can just put it in my application layout css or js files for all my website

Comment: You could, if you don't mind an unmanageable mess of unrelated code and styles. For simplistic sites it may be unnecessary. For sites of any complexity having some form of modularity, even as ad hoc as it is, is a huge benefit: you know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In development it is pretty normal, because assets are not compiled yet and not cached by browser, and not server by webserver without hitting rails (NB: but you have to set all these up for your production deployment)

You can add `gem 'quiet_assets'` to your gemfile to remove assets logging to console, this can be useful.

Comment: thanks. i'll try that. I don't get why rails g controller generates JS/CSS files in assets for my controllers? Is it normal to have controller specific JS/CSS files? i thought most JS/CSS will be for all of the website? i'm going to delete those empty ones.

Comment: thanks; i put gem 'quite_assets' for development and it's good.